# Best approach for using same component for editing and adding data. Mixing component state with redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm building web app in React with Redux. It is simple device manager. I'm using the same component for adding and updating device in database. I'm not sure, if my approach is correct. Here you can find parts of my solution:

**UPDATE MODE:**

In componentDidMount I'm checking, if deviceId was passed in url (edit mode). If so, I'm calling redux action to get retrieve data from database. I'm using connect function, so when response arrives, It will be mapped to component props.

Here is my mapStateToProps (probably I should map only specific property but it does not matter in this case)

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    ...state
})
```

and componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const deviceId = this.props.match.params.deviceId;
        if (deviceId) {
            this.props.getDevice(deviceId);
            this.setState({ editMode: true });
        }
    }
```

Next, componentWillReceiveProps will be fired and I will be able to call setState in order to populate inputs in my form.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.devices.item) {
        this.setState({
            id: nextProps.devices.item.id,
            name: nextProps.devices.item.name,
            description: nextProps.devices.item.description
        });
    }
}
```

**ADD MODE:**

Add mode is even simpler - I'm just calling setState on each input change.

```
handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({
        [name]: event.target.value,
    });
};
```

That's how my inputs looks:

```
<TextField
    onChange={this.handleChange('description')}
    label="Description"
    className={classes.textField}
    value={this.state.description}
/>
```

I don't like this approach because I have to call setState() after receiving data from backend. I'm also using componentWillReceiveProps which is bad practice.

Are there any better approaches? I can use for example only redux store instead of component state (but I don't need inputs data in redux store). Maybe I can use React ref field and get rid of component state?

Additional question - should I really call setState on each input onChange?

Comment: Use React Router and detect the route. If you are on `/items/create` then you are in add mode. If you are on `/items/:itemId` then you are in edit mode.

Comment: That's what I'm doing in componentDidMount. I'm able to detect edit/add mode, but I'm not sure, if I have to mix component state and redux store

Comment: pass an optional prop to the component: if its id is `undefined`, you are in add mode, otherwise in edit mode. Or simply pass the id as prop of course. Do not use route params in a component, otherwise if in the future you want to show the edit not in a dedicated route, your component will break

Comment: @iskrzycki could you add the `mapStateToProps` you are using in update mode? That way I can provide an example w/o making assumptions.

Comment: @nebuler Question updated but I'm just 'spreading' whole redux store

Comment: Is `device` coming from redux store?

Comment: @nebuler Yes, to be exact, my store contains object named 'devices' with property called 'item' which contains name, desc etc. You can see this in setState call on componentWillReceiveProps

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using `componentWillReceiveProps`, and because you are using redux, you can do:

```
class YourComponent extends React.Component {

    state = {
        // ...
        description: undefined,
    };

    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if (prevState.description === undefined && nextProps.description) {
            return { description: nextProps.description };
        }

        return null;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const deviceId = this.props.match.params.deviceId;
        if (deviceId) {
            this.props.getDevice(deviceId);
            this.setState({ editMode: true });
        }
    }

    handleChange = name => event => {
        this.setState({
            [name]: event.target.value,
        });
    };

    // ...

    render() {
        let { description } = this.state;
        description = description || ''; // use this value in your `TextField`.

        // ...

        return (
            <TextField
                onChange={this.handleChange('description')}
                label="Description"
                className={classes.textField}
                value={description}
            />
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    let props = { ...state };
    const { devices } = state;
    if (devices && devices.item) {
        props = {
            ...props,
            id: devices.item.id,
            name: devices.item.name,
            description: devices.item.description,
        };
    }

    return props;
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
)(YourComponent);
```

You can then access `id`, `name`, and `description` thought `this.props` instead of `this.state`. It works because `mapStateToProps` will be evaluated every time you update the redux store. Also, you will be able to access `description` through `this.state` and leave your `TextField` as is. You can read more about `getDerivedStateFromProps` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops).

As for your second question, calling `setState` every time the input changes is totally fine; that's what's called a controlled component, and the react team (nor me) encourage its use. See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Comment: Ok it looks quite nice, but it probably won't resolve my problem. I was using `componentWillReceiveProps` mainly because I was calling `setState()` there (to fill textboxes). As you can see in last code snippet in my question, `this.state.description` is used as a value for input. That's why I'm confused - textboxes are using component state, but data received from backend is connected to props instead on component state. Probably I can call `setState()` in `mapStateToProps()`, but I'm not sure if it's ok. Maybe I have to switch to 100% redux store...